# hide ID from URL using php

Tags: php

I have tried many methods to hide a product ID from the URL but nothing worked for me!
I have tried to hide the ID by using the `.htaccess`
Plus, I am working on localhost using xampp server

This is my code that helped me remove the .php extension but the ID kept showing while going from product to another.

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: Just a thought. You could 'hide' (hash) product IDs in the URL with https://hashids.org/php/

Comment: Explain "hiding product ID". What do you have, and what do you want? Of course you need to have the IDs in the URL in some form, unless you're making POST requests only, if they are to be communicated to the server.

Comment: I have a product page, when the user clicks on any product it will redirect him to the product detail page. So when redirected, the product ID will be seen in the URL. For example, my URL will be like this:  http://localhost/projectname/productid=1. I want the URL to be http://localhost/projectname/product.